# Webservice Callout failed

Tags: soap, salesforce

We have a custom Integration for Docusign in Salesforce. A week ago, we changed the password in Docusign. Since then we are not able to access Docusign's API. Below is the Error Message which shows up in Debug Log.

Error: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: One or both of Username and Password are invalid. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=missing in Web.Config

Please advise!

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the username or password that is being sent to the API is wrong. Try capturing the Callout request is the debug log to see what values are being sent.